# How to format references in APA 6 style in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, apa6

I am very new to Latex/Lyx. Now I'm writing my thesis in Lyx and I have put all my references in Jabref. My references have to be in APA 6 format for which I have downloaded biblatex-apa and apa6 packages from CTAN as suggested in previous posts. However, I am really confused as to how I can "incorporate" those packages in Lyx or add APA 6 to Lyx.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just tried using the apa6.lyx layout. When starting a new document, go to templates and select apa6.lyx. That will help you format your entire document using APA6 format.

If you are talking about just "incorporating" packages, the method varies (AFAIK). On Linux (my preferred system is ArchLinux), I just download the packages, and then (in LyX) click on Tools -> Reconfigure. That re-configures everything, finding all the class  files and you are ready to fo after a restart.

In Windows, with MikTeX, you update/install needed packages and then do the same in LyX.

If it is just references - I am still learning.

Another answer to look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41772/42648

Hope this helps.